# Вывод <span> элемента Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Есть сайт с тестами, после ответа на вопрос появляется ответ и я пытаюсь его выделить и записать в переменную, но все осложняется тем, что ответ находится в span

```html
<div class="tooltip-incorrect-answer-content">
    <ul class="">
      <li class="checked">
        <span class="item-text">Нет, неправильно</span>
      </li>
      <li class="not-checked">
        <span class="item-text">Да, правильно</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Мне нужно вытащить данные span из class="checked", но при попытке не выдает вообще ничего, никакого текста. Результаты поиска есть, но текст из него не извлекается

```py
ans_list = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('checked')
print(ans_list)
print('ans-0')
print(ans_list[0].text)
print('ans-1')
print(ans_list[2].text)
print('end')
```

Вывод в консоль

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="6ccdaff6cb28ba21de6086ce8b5c6ae1", element="a569d2e2-91b8-4836-89cb-084011543801")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="6ccdaff6cb28ba21de6086ce8b5c6ae1", element="66e61596-a873-4866-9964-b893da7d25e6")>]
ans-0

ans-1

end
```

Мне нужно найти решение, которое позволит после нахождения элемента с классом `tooltip-incorrect-answer-content` найти по следующему классу `checked` вытащить весь текст из элемента на уровень ниже, который находится в span

То есть, как в идеале я представляю:

```py
example = driver.find_element_by_class_name("tooltip-incorrect-answer-content")
output = example.find_element_by_class_name('checked')
print (output.text)  # Нет, неправильно
```

Answer (score 1):

Все решилось благодаря `.get_attribute("textContent")`, но при этом `.text()` не работает
Чтобы все работало находим span элемент или xpath выше него и применяем `.get_attribute("textContent")`

```
ans = []
for el in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='tooltip-incorrect-answer-content']"):
    ans.append(el.get_attribute("textContent"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо за ответ - мне реально именно это помогло получить результат, спасибо! Вариант получения текста из конкретного тэга из множества тэгов, не используя цикл и список для хранения.

```
transcription_word = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-hidden='true' and @data-location='1']/child::div[1]")        
print(transcription_word.get_attribute('textContent'))  # ПОЛУЧЕНИЕ ТЕКСТА ИЗ ТЭГА SPAN
transcription = transcription_word.get_attribute('textContent')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо».  Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [проголосовать за вопросы и ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), которые сочтёте полезными. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/781232)

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, прямо в теле ответа (нажав [edit]) что нового добавляет ваш ответ.